# Saving data in MAT format in C#

Tags: c#, matlab, mat

I need to save some data in C#.NET and then access them with MATLAB for further process. Is there a way to create the .mat file in C#?

The data I am trying to save are as follows in xml format:

```
<HandData>
   <HandPoint X="0" Y="0" Z="954.1804" />
   <Handrectangle X="-70" Y="-70" Width="140" Height="140" />
   <Skeleton>
       <Line X="-25" Y="-3" />
       <Line X="-24" Y="-2" />
       ....
   </Skeleton>
</HandData>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to save it as a `.csv`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I don't know MATLAB very well, so I didn't know that I could also save my data as csv. :)

Comment: Well you're saving from C#. To *load* it in Matlab check out either `csvread` or `dlmread`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at CSMatIO. Not perfect but usable.
Latest version here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/csmatio/

Discuss it here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16319